# Getting 403/Forbidden Response from BIM360 and Construction Cloud Assets Endpoints

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm attempting to run a GET request against a BIM360 project's `assets` endpoint. Would someone please advise if this is a bug or if I'm missing something?

Though my auth token is working for just about any other endpoint I've tried (`hubs`, `projects`, `top folders`, and `folder`), I keep getting a `403` response from the server:

```
{
  "title": "Forbidden",
  "detail": "Forbidden",
  "errorCode": "GENERAL_ERROR",
  "type": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/assets/v1/error-codes/GENERAL_ERROR"
}
```

The request that produced this:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/assets/v2/projects/{project_id}/assets \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ...'
```

My app is registered in the account admin page, and the account I'm auth'd with here is an admin. My app also has BIM360 and Construction Cloud selected:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Walker, I just gave it a try myself.  It is working.  Could you make sure you have a correct  parameters?  For example, project id, i.e., verify you have an access in UI. scope has read, and use 3LO. (Assets does not support 2LO)

Comment: Hey Mikako - thank you for responding. I'm using a project ID from the `/project/v1/hubs/:hub_id/projects` endpoint, and this project ID works on other endpoints such as the folder endpoint. I've tried including and removing the `b.` in the project ID but both yield the same result. 

The user I'm auth'd as is the creator of the hub and admin of the project. It can view/add/delete/edit documents in the UI. Scope is also `read` when getting the 3L token.

With all of this, I'm still getting the 403. Is there something else I may be missing here?

Comment: Hi Walker, do you want to try using a tool like postman?

Comment: I’m using insomnia to build and send the request. The curl I pasted is generated from insomnia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue - the project I was querying didn't have `Assets` enabled within the Project Admin. Once I enabled `Assets`, I was able to hit the endpoint successfully. If anyone else is looking at this issue in the future, follow [these steps](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Assets/files/set-up-assets/BIM360D-Assets-set-up-assets-set-up-html-html.html) to enable Assets.

May I offer a couple of feedback requests for the AD team to consider?

- Update the error message to explain what's actually happening. The `Forbidden` code is a little misleading here. Responders to the question and I thought this was an issue with the token/user/etc when really it wasn't.
- Mention the requirement that `Assets` should be enabled in the *Before You Begin* sections of the assets tutorials and/or the assets endpoint docs.

Comment: I'm glad to read you have solved the problem.  I will pass the your suggestion to the documentation team. (I did suggest  "verify you have an access in UI.", too. ;-)